# permutations with characters and NA values without repetitions and without exchanges in R

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

I am very very new to programming and R and I already got a complex task and I need help.

Let's assume I have this data set

| #1 | #2 | #3 | #4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | a | NA | b |
| a | b | c | d |
| h | i | a | d |
| NA | t | h | NA |

I need to output permutations without repetitions and without exchanges ignoring NA of each row.
So first row would provide "ab" value (no "ba" value).
Second row would output "ab", "ac", "ad", "bc", "bd", "cd".
Output for better understanding:

| #1 | #2 | #3 | #4 | perm.1 | perm.2 | perm.3 | perm.4 | perm.5 | perm.6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | a | NA | b | ab | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| a | b | c | d | ab | ac | ad | bc | bd | cd |
| h | i | a | d | hi | ha | hd | ai | id | ad |
| NA | t | h | c | th | tc | hc | NA | NA | NA |

Also, I would need to do these steps after I have permutations listed but I will sort out myself.

1. Remove each row where there is only one value and others are NA.
2. count each perm output.

For example in this case we have ab = 2, ad = 2 and all other permutations are = 1

I tried to play around with gtools permutations and combinations functions but I was not able to come close to solution.

Data frame consists of 30k rows and 42 columns.

head(df)

```
      1   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33
1   ara urd <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   eng spa  rus <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  <NA> eng  ger <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4  <NA> fre  ger  eng <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  <NA> eng  fre <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  <NA> eng  fre  slo  por  dut  pol <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
7  <NA> eng  ger  fre  ita  spa <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
8  <NA> ger  eng  fre <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
9  <NA> fre  slo  por  dut  pol  cat <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
10 <NA> eng  fre <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
     34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42 id
1  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  1
2  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
3  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  3
4  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  4
5  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  5
6  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  6
7  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  7
8  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  8
9  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  9
10 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 10
```

dput(head(df, 10)

```
structure(list(`1` = c("ara", "eng", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `2` = c("urd", "spa", "eng", "fre", "eng", "eng", "eng", 
"ger", "fre", "eng"), `3` = c(NA, "rus", "ger", "ger", "fre", 
"fre", "ger", "eng", "slo", "fre"), `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, "eng", 
NA, "slo", "fre", "fre", "por", NA), `5` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "por", "ita", NA, "dut", NA), `6` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"dut", "spa", NA, "pol", NA), `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "pol", 
NA, NA, "cat", NA), `8` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), `9` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `10` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    `11` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), `12` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `13` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `14` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `15` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `16` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `17` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `18` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `19` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `20` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `21` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `22` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `23` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `24` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `25` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `26` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `27` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `28` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `29` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `30` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `31` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `32` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `33` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `34` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `35` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `36` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `37` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `38` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `39` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `40` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `41` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `42` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), id = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please share with us the result of `dput(head(your_data))` in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the first part of your question to get an ouptut with the combinations, you can do:

### Update with considerable speed improvement and data set with comparable real life size (30k rows, 42 columns)

```
# Creating the test data. Note how I added an ID column that we need to the grouping and identification
df <- matrix(data = sample(c(NA, letters), size = 30000*42, replace = TRUE), ncol = 42, nrow = 30000) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(id = row_number())

# Now run everything
df_new <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(-id) |> 
  filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  summarize(x1 = combn(value, 2, simplify = TRUE)[1,],
            x2 = combn(value, 2, simplify = TRUE)[2,]) |> 
  mutate(perm_number = 1:n()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(perms = str_c(x1, x2)) |> 
  select(-x1, -x2) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = perms,
              names_from = perm_number,
              names_prefix = "perms.") |> 
  left_join(x = df,
            y = _,
            by = "id")
```

With the above test data, the runtime is ~34s for me which I think is good enough for the size of the task:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  34.34    1.00   35.49
```

```
# Using the initial test data with 4 rows, the result would look like:
    x1 x2   x3   x4 id perms.1 perms.2 perms.3 perms.4 perms.5 perms.6
1 <NA>  a <NA>    b  1      ab    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
2    a  b    c    d  2      ab      ac      ad      bc      bd      cd
3    h  i    a    d  3      hi      ha      hd      ia      id      ad
4 <NA>  t    h <NA>  4      th    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

---

### OLD

```
# Create the data
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA,     "a",    "h",    NA),
                 x2 = c("a",    "b",    "i",    "t"),
                 x3 = c(NA,     "c",    "a",    "h"),
                 x4 = c("b",    "d",    "d",    NA))

df |> 
  mutate(perms = apply(across(everything()), 1, function(x) combn(x[!is.na(x)], 2, simplify = FALSE))) |> 
  mutate(perm_length = max(lengths(perms))) |> 
  unnest_wider(perms) |> 
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("..."),
              .fn   = ~paste0("perm.", str_remove(., "..."))) |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("perm."), ~unlist(map(.x = .,
                                                 .f = ~ str_c(unlist(.), collapse = "")))),
         across(starts_with("perm."), ~ifelse(. == "", NA_character_, .)))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 11
  x1    x2    x3    x4    perm.1 perm.2 perm.3 perm.4 perm.5 perm.6 perm_length
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>        <int>
1 NA    a     NA    b     ab     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA               6
2 a     b     c     d     ab     ac     ad     bc     bd     cd               6
3 h     i     a     d     hi     ha     hd     ia     id     ad               6
4 NA    t     h     NA    th     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA               6
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you help! I am running this function now and it looks like it will take ages. I wonder if there is any faster way to get the outcome for 30k rows. BTW: Here I had to change it 2 to 0 else it would show n < m. function(x) combn(x[!is.na(x)], 2, simplify = FALSE

Comment: the two shoudl actually not be changed to 0 because what the 2 does is telling you how many elements (m) you will take out of n. And in your case you wanted to have all combinations with two elements. Changing it to 0 shoudl actually give no results. As for the runtime, there might be faster solutions, but keep in mind that you want to take all two-way combinations out of 42 columns (which results in 861 columns) of 30k cases. But the unnesting in my code indeed takes ages. I'll see if I can find a better solution.

Comment: See my updated code and check if it works. Please also give this answer (in which I invested quite some time) and the other answers by a) upvoting them if they are helpful and b) choose one as your accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to upvote but I am not able yet. I will definitely submit as accepted answer. I can't test the code at this moment but I think I missed one very important part. All my chars consists of 3 letters but not 1 as in example. So "abc" "def" would need to become "abcdef"

Comment: Which they will. The code doesn't care about the input, i.e. if your values are "a" or "asdhja" or 1245.

Comment: I think it's throwing me an error n < m where row has only one occurence. Looking how to remove rows with only one occurence.

Comment: Just count the number of NAs across your 42 columns, then filter on responses where that number is < 41.

Comment: I cleaned the table and then ran a function which did not give any output (I assumed it was working in background) then suddenly my r.cloud goes to sleep. I hit resume and it does not have my cleaning efforts saved. And it happened twice. I am very new to R, maybe I should not do such big equations in cloud studio?

Comment: It would be helpful if you‘d provide a reproducible example. You don‘t need to give us your 30k rows. A subset of e.g. 10 rows or so would already help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited my post with head, and dput(head). I ran your provided solution on first 10 rows and got the needed result! Nice! The problem is with rstudio cloud when it's trying to run 34k rows. Will need to test on installable.

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution (using @deschen's `data.frame`).

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA,     "a",    "h",    NA),
                 x2 = c("a",    "b",    "i",    "t"),
                 x3 = c(NA,     "c",    "a",    "h"),
                 x4 = c("b",    "d",    "d",    NA))

cbind(
  df,
  setNames(
    as.data.frame(
      t(
        simplify2array(
          lapply(
            as.data.frame(t(df)),
            function(x) {
              y <- combn(x[!is.na(x)], 2, paste0, TRUE, collapse = "")
              length(y) <- choose(length(x), 2)
              y
            }
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    paste0("perm.", seq_len(choose(nrow(df), 2)))
  )
)
#>      x1 x2   x3   x4 perm.1 perm.2 perm.3 perm.4 perm.5 perm.6
#> V1 <NA>  a <NA>    b     ab   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> V2    a  b    c    d     ab     ac     ad     bc     bd     cd
#> V3    h  i    a    d     hi     ha     hd     ia     id     ad
#> V4 <NA>  t    h <NA>     th   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

results <-  setDT(dt)[, .(idx = .I, p = apply(.SD, 1, function(x) { x <- na.omit(x); ifelse(length(x) > 1, list(combn(x, 2, paste0, collapse = "")), NA) }))]
results <- results[!is.na(p), .(p = unlist(p)), idx][, i := rleid(p, prefix = "perm."), idx]
counts <- results[, .N, p]
results <- merge(dt[, idx := .I], dcast(results, idx ~ i, value.var = "p"), by = "idx")[, idx := NULL][]
```

**output**

```
results

     c1 c2   c3   c4 perm.1 perm.2 perm.3 perm.4 perm.5 perm.6
1: <NA>  a <NA>    b     ab   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2:    a  b    c    d     ab     ac     ad     bc     bd     cd
3:    h  i    a    d     hi     ha     hd     ia     id     ad
4: <NA>  t    h <NA>     th   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>

counts

     p N
 1: ab 2
 2: ac 1
 3: ad 2
 4: bc 1
 5: bd 1
 6: cd 1
 7: hi 1
 8: ha 1
 9: hd 1
10: ia 1
11: id 1
12: th 1
```

**data**

```
dt <- data.frame(
  c1 = c(NA, "a", "h", NA, "z"),
  c2 = c("a", "b", "i", "t", NA),
  c3 = c(NA, "c", "a", "h", NA),
  c4 = c("b", "d", "d", NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = F
)
```